# setRetainInstance(true) does not persist member variables of the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a View-less Fragment to store some data during orientation change of my Activity. It looks roughly like this:

```
public class BoardActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private DataHandler mDataHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialize the data handler
        mDataHandler = (DataHandler)mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("data");
        if (mDataHandler == null) {
            mDataHandler = new DataHandler();
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(mDataHandler, "data").commit();

            // initialize the data
            mDataHandler.mThreads = ...;
        } else {

            // here, the data is taken and the ListView is filled again.
            fillView();
        }
    }

    public static class DataHandler extends Fragment {
        private Topic[] mThreads;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is, that when the Activity is left (vor example with the home button) and for some reason is killed in the background, the app crashes upon restart of that Activity. The reason is that although the Fragment `mDataHandler` is found by the FragmentManager, its Member variable (`mThreads`) is `null`.

How come the Fragment itself can be retained but its variables are set to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come the Fragment itself can be retained but its variables are set to zero?

The fragment was not retained. Retained fragments are retained only for configuration changes. You did not go through a configuration change. Your process was terminated, because Android needed the RAM to support other apps.

Comment: I thought that this was not true? I mean, if you have 5 activities open in the stack, Android never terminates them to free up the ram. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Then why is `mDataHandler` not null when I get it from the FragmentManager? This is exactly why I check that.

Comment: @Lefteris: "if you have 5 activities open in the stack, Android never terminates them to free up the ram. Am I wrong here?" -- devices do not have infinite RAM. Android will *tend* to clear out processes that are empty (e.g., all activities were `finish()`-ed), but eventually will have to start terminating processes that do have running activities.

Comment: @janoliver: "Then why is mDataHandler not null when I get it from the FragmentManager?" -- I am going to guess that you returned to your app via the recent-tasks list. In that case, Android may still have the saved instance state (`Bundle` and `onSaveInstanceState()`) and therefore may *recreate* your fragments that existed in the activity previously. However, since it terminated the process, it cannot *retain* the fragments, which is why the fragments themselves are comparatively empty.

Comment: That makes sense. However, before my app crashes, no `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called... What would be the best solution for this? The way I already did it seems not so nice.

Comment: @janoliver: "However, before my app crashes, no onRestoreInstanceState() is called" -- `onRestoreInstanceState()` like `setRetainInstance()`, **is only for configuration changes**. "What would be the best solution for this?" -- I have no way of answering that. However, clearly, somehow, you are actually able to start up the activity and its fragments the first time, so dealing with coming back after having had your process terminated should not be significantly different. The existence of your fragment is not evidence that *all* initialization has been done.